# Linear map between $M^*\otimes_RN\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(M,N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

I'm reading a lecture note about tensors, following is a proposition:

> For $R$-module $M$ and $N$, there is a linear map
>   $M^*\otimes_RN\rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(M,N)$ sending each elements
>   tensor $\varphi\otimes n$ in $M^*\otimes_RN$ to the linear map
>   $M\rightarrow N$ defined by $m\mapsto \varphi(m)n$.

I think it is obvious and argue like this:

We have a bilinear map from $M^*\times N$ to $\text{Hom}_R(M,N)$ defined by $(\varphi,n)\mapsto \varphi(\cdot)n$. So by universal property of tensors, we get a linear map from $M^*\otimes_RN$ to $\text{Hom}_R(M,N)$.

However, the author of the note does not prove like this and argues seems more complicated:

> The function $M^*\times M\times N\rightarrow N$ given by
>   $(\varphi,m,n)\mapsto \varphi(m)n$ is trilinear, so (by a mentioned
>   theorem) this trilinear map induces a bilinear map
>   $B:(M^*\otimes_RN)\times M\rightarrow N$ where $B(\varphi\otimes
> m,n)=\varphi(m)n$. For fixed $t\in M^*\otimes_RN$, $B(t,\cdot)$ is in
>   $\text{Hom}_R(M,N)$, so we have a linear map $f:M^*\times
> N\rightarrow\text{Hom}_R(M,N)$ defined by $t\mapsto B(t,\cdot)$.

I wonder why the author argued like this? Is there any problem in my simple proof?

Comment: you're thing sounds legit to me

Answer (score 1):

He's essentially doing the same thing in a more complicated way for no apparent reason. Your proof is fine. The details of his "why" probably lie in the structure of the document itself. Maybe it's just a bad proof, or maybe he wasn't okay writing $\varphi( \cdot )n$ or something, but without the book I can't tell.

Hope that helps,

Comment: OK..Maybe he is just showing some fancy tricks..thx~